# Alternate merge strings in BASH

Tags: string, bash, shell, scripting

From

```
KS=$(locate acpi-support | grep "/etc/rc" | cut -f4 -d/ | tr -dc '[K,S]')
LEVELS=$(locate acpi-support | grep "/etc/rc" | cut -f3 -d/ | tr -dc '[0-9]')
echo $KS
echo $LEVELS
```

I get the following outputs:

```
KSSSS
12345
```

What I'd like to do is to merge alternatively the previous outputs in this way:

```
K1 S2 S3 S4 S5
```

I tried whit nested *for* loops but without success, how could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a for loop to iterate over the characters in one of the strings and then use bash's substring functionality to print out characters. This is shown below:

```
KS="KSSSS"
LEVELS="12345"
unset result
for (( i=0; i<${#KS}; i++ )); do
  result+="${KS:$i:1}${LEVELS:$i:1} "
done
echo "$result"
```

Output:

```
K1 S2 S3 S4 S5
```

Comment: I like the way it is more general `${#KS}` and the `result+=` issue, to make it more general than mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$ KS=KSSSS

$ LEVELS=12345

$ awk '{n=length/2;for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print $i$(i+n)}' ORS=" " FS= <<< "$KS$LEVELS"
K1 S2 S3 S4 S5
```

Comment: What a powerful tool!
Thanks :)

Comment: @fedorqui I wasn't going to but I saw your comment. I know there is a more elegant solution for this, it will come to me!

Answer (score 1):

Python one-liner

```
$ KS="KSSSS"
$ LEVELS="12345"
$ python -c 'import sys; print " ".join([k+v for k,v in zip(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])])' $KS $LEVELS
K1 S2 S3 S4 S5
$
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
KS="KSSSS"
LEVELS="12345"
for i in {0..4}; do
  echo ${KS:$i:1}${LEVELS:$i:1}
done
```

Although for sure `awk` guru will come to rescue with better one-liner way : )

To make it appear all on the same line:

```
for i in {0..4}; do
  echo ${KS:$i:1}${LEVELS:$i:1} | awk '{printf("%s ",$1)}
done
```

Comment: Thanks in advance, but I think that's not a generic way to get my goal; on an other try I get SKSKK and 0245, the for you suggested me should be modified, since I may not always have a complete range from 1 to 5 :)
I'll take a look to awk!

Comment: @dogbane generalized it. Having a `for (( i=0; i<${#KS}; i++ ));` loop, which I think it's better. Did not update my answer not to copy.

Answer (score -1):

If you make `KS` and `LEVELS` arrays instead of strings, you can use `paste`:

```
KS=( $(locate acpi-support | grep "/etc/rc" | cut -f4 -d/ | tr -dc '[K,S]') )
LEVELS=( $(locate acpi-support | grep "/etc/rc" | cut -f3 -d/ | tr -dc '[0-9]') )

paste -d"\0" <( printf "%s\n" ${KS[@]}) <( printf "%s\n" ${LEVELS[@]})
```